# Forcing to wait HTTP get request until finish in Angular

Tags: angular

I have service code like:

```
 async read() {
        let p = await this.http.get('/api/setting').toPromise();
        this.data= p.json();
    }
```

And I am calling that service method in a component's ngInit() method as follows :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._settings.read();
        this.getAll();
    }
```

My problem is `getAll()` method runs at the same time with `read()` method.

**But I want to run `getAll()` method after `read()` completed. How can I do that?**

*PS: My angular version is 4.2.5 and I do not want to change it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `read` method is async. You need to `await` it like this

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this._settings.read();
    this.getAll();
}
```

Comment: Gald that I can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways. One way is to use Observable subscribe

```
read() {
            return await this.http.get('/api/setting').subscribe((res) => {
             this.data= p.json();
          });        
        } 

ngOnInit() {
    this._settings.read().subscribe((res) => {
      this.getAll();
    });        
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted. I clearly mentioned this is one of the many ways. In future if user want to load entirely different data inside ngOnInit, we are blocking that operations as it will wait till promise resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can always resort to plain JavaScript if you really need to make a synchronous call:

```
public myFunction() {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET", 'https://filltext.herokuapp.com/?rows=1&name={firstName}', false);
    r.send();
    return JSON.parse(r.responseText)[0];
}
```